# R: "testing if installed package can be loaded"

Tags: r

I have a custom R package. I try to install it on a Windows machine (64 bit R, if it matters). Everything is fine with a few warnings, the package is installed, then R wants to test if the installed package can be loaded. Then I get the following message:

```
Warning: Failed to load RGtk2 dynamic library, attempting to install it.

Please install GTK+ from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.22/gtk+-bundle_2.22.1-20101227_win32.zip

 If the package still does not load, please ensure that GTK+ is installed and that it is on your PATH environment variable

 IN ANY CASE, RESTART R BEFORE TRYING TO LOAD THE PACKAGE AGAIN

 Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 

 can not load shared object '<not relevant>/R/win-library/3.0/RGtk2/libs/i386/RGtk2.dll':

 LoadLibrary failure: the specified module could not be found
```

The message is printed repeatedly a few hundred times. Then the following happens:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RGtk2', details:

 call: NULL

 error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

 Error : package 'RGtk2' could not be loaded
```

After that, R removes the already installed package. If the installation process is aborted after the package indices are built but before the installer removes the package, the package can be loaded with `library` and works fine. Other packages that require RGtk2 work fine as well.

There seems to be no such problem on Linux machines, although I did not test it extensively.

Why does it happen?

P.S.: Just to be clear: I am aware of the --no-test-load option of R CMD INSTALL. If this option is used, everything is ok. So the question is not how to make the package work. The question is more like "what happens during the test load that does not happen during a regular load".

Comment: "Everything is fine with a few warnings" often means that everything is not fine. Is RGtk2 installed on the system and can be loaded on its own?

Comment: Edited for clarity. Yes, it is installed, it can be loaded, it displays everything it should display.

Comment: During test load R tries to load package in separate process. May be some troubles with interprocess communication? Do you have the same problem with other packages?
https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b7a83709ca845a78052716060a8802b985d1aeae/src/library/tools/R/install.R#L1212

Comment: @testlnord oh. I didn't know it was in separate process. No, I've never seen it with other packages, but I don't use RGtk2 a lot.

Comment: @zabolekar I have such problems when I run RStudio from docker container and try to install any package. But I think my problems are more about Docker than about R or RStudio.